# CodeNameNotUniqueException after applying hotfix Kentico 7

Tags: kentico

I am having a 'CodeNameNotUniqueException' error whereby after upgrading from v7.0.37 to v7.0.70 I am getting an error on loading my website. It looks like it is related to something to do with roles as the code name 'int-sg-ctx-nz-xa6-publisheddesktopoffice2013' is a role in my website. It basically happens to all the roles and not just this one. This is the error message that I get in event viewer:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: CodeNameNotUniqueException 
Exception message: The object with code name 'int-sg-ctx-nz-xa6-publisheddesktopoffice2013' already exists.
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`2.SetInfoInternal(InfoType info)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`2.SetInfo(InfoType info)
at CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfoProvider.EnsureRolesAndSitesInternal(UserInfo uInfo, Boolean isWindowsAuth)
at CMS.CMSHelper.AuthenticationHelper.EnsureExternalUser(UserInfo uInfo)
at CMS.CMSHelper.AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateWindowsUser(String userName, SecurityIdentifier sid, String siteName, String[] roles)
at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.GetCurrentUser(Boolean& loadUserData, Boolean cacheResult)
at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.get_CurrentUser()
at CMSAppBase.CMSSessionStart(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
Request URL: http://aainsurance/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx?aliaspath=/home 
Request path: /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx 
User host address: 10.212.210.58 
User: INT\U362515 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: NTLM 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\AAI.Intranet 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 58 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\AAI.Intranet 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`2.SetInfoInternal(InfoType info)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`2.SetInfo(InfoType info)
at CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfoProvider.EnsureRolesAndSitesInternal(UserInfo uInfo, Boolean isWindowsAuth)
at CMS.CMSHelper.AuthenticationHelper.EnsureExternalUser(UserInfo uInfo)
at CMS.CMSHelper.AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateWindowsUser(String userName, SecurityIdentifier sid, String siteName, String[] roles)
at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.GetCurrentUser(Boolean& loadUserData, Boolean cacheResult)
at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.get_CurrentUser()
at CMSAppBase.CMSSessionStart(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState()
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Can anyone help with this? As of now I've had to rollback the database and restore the files for version 37 which is a shame as this version is not fully compatible with IE11.

Answer (score 2):

Are you somewhere editing/creating user`s ID or GUID manually in your custom code?

Just FYI - kentico 7 has released more than one year before release of IE11 so it is really hard to support not existing product... Source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) [devnet](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-cms-7-released---full-feature-list)